The file is locked by: "Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (2388)
My system is keeping a lock on some DLLs, causing me to exit and reopen visual studio in order to continue work.
After running and exiting my C# XAF 24.1.5 Winforms application in the VS 17.11.2.
Like most Winforms XAF solutions the Win project references the Module Project which in turn references the EntityFrameworkCore dlls
On trying to Clean the Win Project (after running it)
I get:
warning MSB3061: Unable to delete file `"C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\MyXAFWin\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Castle.Core.dll". The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\MyXAFWin\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\Castle.Core.dll' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (2388)"

The same message for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
After a while (about 20 minutes) the error goes away.
I consider question is not a duplicate of this question because it is happening when I clean the project and on the referenced dlls rather than the .exe
Update
Trying Cheap Nightbot's suggestion I see

Only I dont want to close Visual Studio. I already know that exiting Visual Studio will solve the problem. I don't want to keep exiting Visual Studio.
I am running Visual Studio 17.11.2
I am wondering if maybe I am not disposing something where I should be.
Update
In Task Manager, Processes, Apps, Visual Studio I see

Update
My Module Project is
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <CheckEolTargetFramework>false</CheckEolTargetFramework>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;EasyTest</Configurations>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CA1416</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Model.DesignedDiffs.xafml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Model.DesignedDiffs.xafml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.21.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.CodeAnalysis" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ConditionalAppearance" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Objects" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Office" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.TreeListEditors" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Validation" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.Base" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="5.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="8.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

And the win project is
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <CheckEolTargetFramework>false</CheckEolTargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ApplicationIcon>MyXAF.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;EasyTest</Configurations>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CA1416</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ListView" Alias="ListView" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Model.xafml" />
    <None Remove="Images\Logo.svg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Model.xafml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\Logo.svg" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\ExpressAppLogo.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.CodeAnalysis" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.EFCore" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.FileAttachment.Win" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Office.Win" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.ReportsV2.Win" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.TreeListEditors.Win" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Validation.Win" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Design" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.Base" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl.EFCore" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.RichEdit.Export" Version="24.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Win.Design" Version="24.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SBD24.MyXAF.Module\SBD24.MyXAF.Module.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


That usually means that the VS debug host doesn't close (see task manager). Don't know what to do about it, but it may get you on the right track.

What Process name should I be looking for in task manager?

Maybe File Locksmith in Microsoft PowerToys might be helpful in this situation. It can be installed from Microsoft Store or from GitHub releases.

In References, when you right-click and select Properties, do you have Copy Local = True?  make sure you do.

Where should I see references? I see Dependencies but no references.

I have also faced same issue after downgrading the visual studio with my college's previous working version it got resolved. It's because of some background process taking time to unlock your file after closing the program or might be the program not properly closed completely.
You can try updating or downgrading the visual studio with previous worked version.
Alternatively, You can try using IOBit Unlocker or any other unlocking tool that will unlock the file and allow you to delete/rename/modify.

Thank you. What version of VS was good for you?

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.8.0 as of now I am not getting this issue

This post is not exactly the answer to your question, but it may help to solve the problem.
Let's check the following:

1- For large solutions including a number of sub-projects and installed
NuGet packages, be sure to run "Visual Studio" with full access
(administrator access level) with a local computer account. It is better to use it
with the same login that you installed "Visual Studio", and that login
should be the administrator. I think, otherwise, some parts and
extensions of "Visual Studio" may not work properly and be problematic.
Also, all "Visual Studio" processes may not run in the same "Security
Context" and access problems may arise. Also, when the error occurs, check with "Task Manager" to see if the "devenv.exe" process is running as the user you expected.
2- Antivirus is important:
If you do not have an antivirus installed
on that computer, be sure to check the computer from time to time,
especially the "Visual Studio" installation folder, using online virus scanners
("ESET", "Kaspersky", "Norton", etc.). If "Visual Studio" is affected by
malware, the malware may try to infect the executable files of the project and during operation, it may cause the files to lock (.exe or .dll files).
If you have an installed antivirus, it
should be noted that some antiviruses are very sensitive to changes in
executable files and may interfere with executable file changes.
Also, if keystrokes are processed and logged in your C# code, the antivirus may block that executable files (.exe or .dll files) as a type of keylogger (spyware).
Or if there is a certain type of email sending in your program, it may still be blocked as a program with malicious behavior.
It is better to temporarily add the project folder as an
exception in the antivirus settings (exclusions list), or temporarily disable the
antivirus when cleaning the project build, and see if the problem
still occurs?
3- If possible, move the "Castle.Core" NuGet package and related items
to a new project in the solution and reference that project in the
main project. See if there is a change in the error message or not.
4- Remove or disable third-party plugins and extensions as much as possible from
"Visual Studio". If you are using software license management tools,
temporarily disable that tool. Some software license management
services may monitor the executable file or main dlls of the project
to prevent changes.
5- When an error occurs, check each of the folders in the file path to
see if their read-only attribute is selected (checked)? If so, remove the read-only attribute setting and check again. Also
can you delete that file directly in "Windows Explorer" or not. Check if running "Clean" operation twice without rebuilding
changes the error message.

If none of the above items solves the problem and your solution is not too big, create a new solution and add the codes and packages step by step and check to see which part causes the problem.
To get a more accurate answer, you can ask "Microsoft" to resolve the issue (if you haven't already submitted the issue). In "DeveloperCommunity" of "Microsoft", other people have reported similar problems, but Microsoft's answer is to send complete information according to "guidelines" so that it can be checked.
I think what they mean is that you create a "Repo" on "GitHub" (repository) so that dll file locking happens easily and repeatedly for anyone who tests that code, and then send the link of that "Repo" to "Microsoft" or if "Repo" cannot be created and the issue is not related to the project and it's related to the tool, write the specific conditions and settings of "Visual Studio" exactly. Maybe they can examine the matter more closely and give a more suitable answer.
"Microsoft" mentioned that they are monitoring the visual-studio tag on the "Stack Overflow" site and looking into the matter. So maybe if you add the "Repo" link to your question or more details about "Visual Studio" settings and conditions, one of the experts from "Microsoft" will respond.

Use handle.exe from the sysinternals package to see what's actually locking the files. If it isn't the main devenv process you should be able to kill it without shutting down VS. Usually it's not - debug processes and vshost etc are often the culprit.
ProcessHacker is another tool that will give you more info/control of the process tree.  It's quite helpful for tracking down this kind of problem.

FileLocksmith shows that it is devenv that has the lock.

@Kirsten - (1) The handle.exe is more low-level than FileLocksmith.  I'm not sure if it's going to give you the top of the process tree or the actual subprocess that is being problematic.  We could find this out by writing a Console app that launches a subprocess that locks a file and then seeing which of the two processes FileLocksmith identifies as owning the handle for the file. (2) How are you referencing the locked third-party DLLs from MyXAFWin project?  It's possible that the way these files are referenced leads to the conflict.  Posting your proj files could help us help you wrt this

Thankyou @smartcaveman I have added the projects.

Where is Castle coming from?  Is that a DevExpress dependency?

Yes, XAF uses Castle
